# ABPersonViewController is not showing facetime button?

Tags: ios, abaddressbook, abpersonviewcontroller, facetime

I get contacts using `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` and when i select any one of these contacts, i get details of that person using `ABPersonViewController`. From apple documents, we will get face time button on `ABPersonViewController` using `allowsActions:` method. But i did not get face time. I have used following code..

```
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController: 
(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker 
shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person { 
// NSLog(@"shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson"); 
ABPersonViewController *picker = [[ABPersonViewController alloc] init] ; 
picker.personViewDelegate = self; 
picker.displayedPerson = person; 
picker.displayedProperties=@[@(kABPersonPhoneProperty),@(kABPersonEmailProperty),@(kABPersonBirthdayProperty),@(kABPersonOrganizationProperty),@(kABPersonJobTitleProperty),@(kABPersonDepartmentProperty),@(kABPersonNoteProperty),@(kABPersonCreationDateProperty)]; 
picker.allowsActions=YES; 
[self.navigationController pushViewController:picker animated:YES];}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got answer. I have used `[self.navigationController pushViewController:picker animated:YES]` instead of `[peoplePicker pushViewController:picker animated:YES]`. That's why i didn't get what i wanted. The reason is, when i write `[self.navigationController pushViewController:picker animated:YES]`, the default `ABPersonViewController` will be come. So facetime, shareContact and Add to Favorites buttons are not there. But when i write `[peoplePicker pushViewController:picker animated:YES]`, created custom `ABPersonViewController` and all buttons are there using allowsActions: method.

```
 - (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:
    (ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker
          shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person {

                ABPersonViewController *picker = [[ABPersonViewController alloc] init];
                picker.personViewDelegate = self;
                picker.displayedPerson = person;
                picker.displayedProperties = peoplePicker.displayedProperties;
                picker.allowsActions = YES;
               [peoplePicker pushViewController:picker animated:YES];
           return NO;
    }
```